# How to navigate to Windows Phone 8 start screen using C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have built a very basic sound board app by following video tutorial series on channel 9 [http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners]. Each page in the app displays a list of sound tiles, which on tap plays associated sound. I have extended the app to allow user to tile the individual sound to phone's start screen. Everything works fine upto this point.

Now whenever user taps the sound from start screen, I want app tile to just play the sound, however its navigating into the application at the moment. I have raised similar question on channel 9 and the video series author suggested me that its possible by calling NavigationService.GoBack method on OnNavigatedTo event. I tried that, however I am getting exception with message 'Cannot go back when CanGoBack is false'. Here is the channel 9 thread - http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-23-Testing-and-Submitting-to-the-Store

Appreciate if someone helps me to resolve the issue.

Entire source code of my app is available on GitHub at https://github.com/PrasadHonrao/WindowsPhone8/tree/master/SoundJabber

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To programmatically exit an application, you can call:

```
Application.Current.Terminate();
```

Unfortunately, it will work only on Windows Phone 8, this method isn't available on Windows Phone 7.

Comment: I am not sure if this code needs to be implemented in OnNavigatedTo event handler. If I do so, then it terminates the app without playing the sound.

Comment: @PrasadHonrao I'm not sure how you're playing the sound, but there must be some kind of event on the object to indicate when the sound has been loaded or played. But please note that your original requirement "Playing a sound without navigating to the app" is impossible. The best you can do is exiting as soon as the sound is played

Comment: I understand its bit tricky to implement but don't think its impossible. Even channel 9 author has confirmed about it. Even if user taps on the tile and navigates into the application, I need some way to navigate user back to the start screen so that he will always think that he is on start page all the time.

Comment: @PrasadHonrao That's still "navigating to the app", even if you exit immediately. So I stand my point ;) The user will at least have the "tiles moving" animation before your app is loaded, you can't do anything about that. From there, the questions are: will the sound load quickly enough, and will it stop playing once you exit the app. How long is your sound? Nearly instant, or a few seconds?

Comment: Sound is nearly instant however if I terminate the application it doesn't play.

Comment: @PrasadHonrao It just means you're closing the application too quickly. As I mentionned before, I don't know which object you're using to play the sound, but it's likely that there's an event to tell you when the sound has finished loading and/or playing

Comment: Yes, it seems application is closing too quickly. I am using MediaElement to play the sound.

Comment: @PrasadHonrao Then you should try subscribing to the `MediaEnded` event and exit the application when it's triggered. http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediaended(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Okay. That MediaEnded worked very well. However, the functionality is not perfect. As of now it navigates into the app, plays the sound and navigates back to phone start screen. Is there anyway I can restrict this navigation to and from app. i.e. just stay on start screen when user taps on tile. I understand you helped me to resolve  my main query, but I really want to just play the sound and do not want to show navigation effect to and from the start page / application. Thanks.

Comment: @PrasadHonrao As you were already been told: no, you can't prevent the initial navigation to the app. That's because it happens before you app is even loaded, there's strictly nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use navigationService.GoBack when you don't have navigation history.
When you are in your main page and you want to exit your application you can use NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() for remove navigation history.

If you want  play sound for a specifique user.Create Model ou uri sound as parameter.

For information: 
when you use Application.Current.Terminate();.You don't pass in your app.cs.

Comment: I really just want to play that sound file from phone start screen, without navigating into the application. As of now I am able to play the sound file, however once I tap on the sound tile, it navigates into the application page which i want to restrict.

Comment: You just want to play sound when you click on tile?

Comment: Yes. That's the only functionality pending in the app.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest you can do is `Application.Current.Terminate();`