# Goto Home screen

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

App flows is this;

1. User launches the app and see a page with written "Background task started"
2. if user taps Back button app terminates and also background task ends
3. but if user taps Menu button and use other apps then my app continues to run

Now I have two solutions in mind; please help me to solve this.

A. I should have "OK" button; if user taps on it then main menu should be open
B. what to write in Back button so that App not terminates.

In app.xaml

private static Geolocator locator;

```
    public static Geolocator Locator
    {
        get
        {
            lock (typeof(App))
            {
                if (locator == null)
                {
                    locator = new Geolocator();
                    locator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
                    //locator.MovementThreshold = 50;
                    locator.ReportInterval = 10000;
                }
            }
            return locator;
        }
    }
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            App.Locator.PositionChanged += Locator_PositionChanged;
        }

Thanks

Comment: You need to show us some code

Comment: You should be more specific in describing your problem. Right now, I can tell you, that you can override the "back" button, but I don't know the way to use native "home" button behavior, and even if there is a way, the app may not pass the certification process.

Comment: just tell me how to create Home Screen instance to move to Home(Tiles) screen on a button click!

Comment: @user3102858 have you checked out this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609609/how-to-navigate-to-windows-phone-8-start-screen-using-c-sharp

Comment: @Mark, it's not exactly the same. Application.Current.Terminate will close the application immediately with same behavior as back button. The op seems to find a way to programmatically repeat home button tap event.

Comment: @Olter it seemed to me that the goal was to register a background agent and then close the app. Therefore the app closed i.e. can be programmatically terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, there's no way to achieve this.

You can override the back button tap event, but you can't override the home button event.

Moreover, you can't even call a native home button event programmatically.

There's a link with similar question at [msdn forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/c20b500d-aa54-4a1a-a8ab-3d7e8d3eebbb/navigate-to-windows-phone-home-screen-programatically?forum=wpdevelop)

---

**Update**. You still think, that the problem is with back and menu buttons. That seems wrong to me. The problem is, that the background agent isn't activated, when the Application_Closing event is hit.

There are two methods in app.xaml.cs:

Application_Deactivated and Application_Closing. Your background task should be active, if any of them is executed.

```
// Code to execute when the application is deactivated (sent to background, e.g. menu button is hit)
// This code will not execute when the application is closing
private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{

}

// Code to execute when the application is closing (eg, user hit Back)
// This code will not execute when the application is deactivated
private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Set a breakpoint at background agent constructor, and see, if it's hit.

Btw, for your two solutions:

Solution A cannot be done.
Solution B can be done by overriding OnNavigatedFrom method.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {          
            // nothing will happen here
            //base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        }
```

however, that'll be a rude violation of windows-phone navigationservice native behavior. That won't pass the certification.

Comment: so what should I do ? when user press back button; app terminates! Actually Its one page app. Once user open it; it will run in background but if user press back then app terminates

Comment: Does the background agent terminates too? It's a bit strange, because windows-phone always had an issue of non-closing background agent, that annoyed a lot of people, but I've never heard, that the agent once initialized would dispose at app exit. When do you initialize your agent(maybe it's not initialized when the app closes)?

Comment: well, I am not initializing in Close event; ok, Thank you; I am going to do it in Close :) Thanks again

Comment: As I showed my code. I have instance in app.xaml while registering event in main.xaml. how to active agent on close event ?